# Unable to Create many threads in OCP Containers

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, kubernetes-pod, ulimit

Recently we were getting the following exception in one of our Containers which was running a Java application in Openshift 4.2. This container used to run perfectly on Openshift 3.11.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717
```

Within the containers, the ulimits looks perfectly fine. See the below image.

[image: Ulimits]

In Openshift 3.11 the same container could create 4096 Threads. But in Openshift 4.2 it just can create 1024 threads. Please see the Below Images,

OCP 3.11
[image: Openshift 3.11]

OCP 4.2
[image]

From the above ulimits it's evident that docker agent level configurations are done. Also, I have allocated enough memory for OS to create native threads. But I have no clue where this limit is set. How can I increase this global limit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, OpenShift 3 uses *docker* as container runtime whereas OpenShift 4 uses [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/) as container runtime.

According to [Default pids_limit too low](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/issues/1921) - by default there has been a limit to 1024 threads when using cri-o.